# Why is my HTML page horizontally scrollable on mobile screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm trying to make a very basic webpage with html and css that fits on multiple screen sizes. I have the viewport set to the device width, and have tried an initial-scale value anywhere from 0.5 to 2.0, but I can't seem to prevent the base html from expanding off screen. The weirdest thing to me is that when I inspect the html, it says the width is 190px which is supposed to be half of the device width that I'm emulating.

This is my current head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Student Housing Prices: College Park</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/app.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <meta name="description" content="College Park Student Housing Prices" />
    <meta name="author" content="Fill" />
  </head>
```

I've been using @media in the css to resize my divs with the screen size and so far everything else has been fine, but the root html seems to always expand to 2x the actual screen width, despite reporting less pixels than the screen itself!

This is the CSS for a small screen:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  html,
  body {
    max-width: 50%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
  html .content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

I feel like I shouldn't have to use 50% width if 100% width was the *actual* full width of the mobile screen. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you include the contents of the body in index.html

I'm trying to solve the problem in style.css so that the screen on the mobile phone can be 100%, by changing the max-width : 100 on the body

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
html .content {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

}

so that when in mobile mode, the screen width can be up to 390 px. I  hope this helps